# Fastest way to cast Java Objects from memcache

Tags: java, object, casting, memcached

We have a webapp which uses memcache to store objects temporally. We are adding background jobs to cleanup the cache (not based on time based expiration that comes with memcache). Since we have multiple instances of the webapp running, we want to make sure that only one instance is doing the cleanup at any point. So we decided to keep a flag in memcached allowing only one instance to run. Now the question.

I am just storing a flag, it could be an int, String, boolean, heck...even just a char. However queries from memcached returns Objects, which will have to casted to whatever type I pick. If I pick boolean than the object will have to be casted to lang.Boolean which might be more work than just a String.

Which type would you pick?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you are optimising the right thing here????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is pretty much irrelevant. You might want to try encoding it as null/not-null. That way you don't have to cast.

It probably will amount to a rounding error on the total time of the call, especially with a cache look up. If it's a big deal, I'd look to reducing the number of times it's called rather than shorting the execution time.

Answer (score 6):

I would pick the type which most accurately represents the type of data I'm trying to store. It sounds like that would be a Boolean.

It seems *highly* unlikely that the cost of a cast is going to be the bottleneck here. Why are you even bothered about that portion of it? Do you have any measurements/benchmarks to suggest it will make a meaningful difference?

Comment: Agreed. You are inherently working with a network connection when talking to memcached. The time involved with the conversion or cast of this value is likely to be 1000s of time faster than the network. You should not even be worried about this.

Comment: OK, I agree that compared to the network time the casting is pretty negligible. My question was more focused towards 'what do people usually do'. For now I am going to go with what mostly people said here - don't worry about it and do what makes sense avoiding fancy tricks.